# Interpretation of Complex disc around origin as a variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-schemes

Can we think of any complex disc around origin(say $\Delta$) as a projective variety?

I am asking this question because I have encountered the  product $\mathbb{P}^{n} \times \Delta$ in an algebro-geometric context,which I think may be interpreted in $2$ ways:

$(1)$ product of $2$ complex manifolds one of dimension $n$ and other is of dimension $1$ (please correct me if I am wrong)

$(2)$ fiber product of projective space of dimension $n$ and some projective variety in $\mathbb{P}^{n}$.(for my purpose this kind of interpretation will be more relevant,but I don't see how is that the case)

Also can we say that any smooth $r$ dimensional complex manifold is essentially a projective scheme? If so how?

Any help from anyone is welcome

Comment: The point of algebraic varieties is that their function field are finite extensions of the field of rational functions in $k$ variables, whereas the function field of the unit disk contains much more functions for example things like $\sin(1/(z-1))$ with infinitely many isolated zeros

Comment: @reuns, then how can we interpret $\mathbb{P}^{n} \times \Delta$ as a scheme?

Comment: By defining its field of meromorphic functions and for each subset $U$ the subring $O_X(U)$ of meromorphic functions with no pole on $U$. Let $F$ be the field of meromorphic functions on the unit disk $D$ then the function field of $\Bbb{P}^n \times D$ is $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ the field of rational functions in $n$ variables with coefficients in $F$.

Comment: In any case $\mathbb{P}^{n} \times \Delta$, isn't an algebraic variety, so you shouldn't interpret as a scheme as any such interpreation isn't feasible. A smooth complex manifold has absolutely no reason to be (isomorphic to the complex points of) a scheme, it will be the case if it is a closed analytic (holomorphic) submanifold of the projective space.

Comment: @Ahr You meant scheme of finite type instead of scheme ? Why do you think what I defined isn't a scheme.

Comment: What did you define exactly?
What I'm saying is that if $\Delta$ is say an polydisc in $\mathbb{C}^n$, then there's no reasonable way to define a $\mathbb{C}$-scheme $X$, whose complex points identify with $\mathbb{P}^d(\mathbb{C})\times \Delta$.

Comment: The scheme $\bigcup_U Spec(O_X(U))$  where the union is over the open subsets $U$ (in complex topology) of $\Bbb{P}^n \times \Delta$ and $O_X(U)$ is the subring of $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ of functions analytic on $U$ and $F$ is the field of meromorphic functions on $\Delta$. The same construction works for any complex manifold. @Ahr

Comment: Well, let us take $d$=0, as is non essential to the picture, the complex points of your scheme don't correspond to $\Delta$, in fact even putting an analytic topology on them requires some care. What you get does not bear a lot of ressemblance to $\Delta$.

Comment: @Ahr ?? Any point $p \in \Bbb{P}^n\times \Delta$ is a maximal ideal $\{ f \in O_X(U), f(p)=0\}$ for each $U \ni p$. The topology is implied by the choice of the function field and the structure sheaf (that's the point of schemes)

Comment: You get a lot more than that, in the spectrum, and that is just on the level of points. The sheaf you get isn't like the sheaf of holomorphic functions on the polydisc. What is the statement of the property you claim is true here?

Comment: In any case, I wanted to point out to the attention of the OP, that with the usual definition of the analytification functor $X\to X^h$, there exists no $\mathbb{C}$-scheme, $Y$, such that $Y^h$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^d\times \Delta$ where $\Delta$ is a polydisc in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: @Ahr I don't know what you are trying to say. $\mathbb{P}^d\times \Delta$ is the set of maximal ideals of $\bigcup Spec(O_X(U))$ and the complex topology is implied by the structure of $O_{X,p}$

Comment: ?? Could you elaborate on how the "complex topology is implied by the structure of $O_{X,p}$". As I said, usually the analytification functor is defined for $\mathbb{C}$-schemes locally of finite type. If you take $R$ to be the ring of holomorphic functions on the open unit disc on $\mathbb{C}$, I know what $Y=Spec(R)$ is, how do you define a topology on $Y(\mathbb{C})$? How do you define a sheaf on $Y(\mathbb{C})$? And whetevr definition you take, I'm pretty sure you won't get $(\Delta, O_\Delta)$ where $\Delta$ is the unit disc and $O_\Delta$ the sheaf of holomorphic functions on it.

Comment: My experience is that you're secretly working in a complex analytic setting, even though you're in an algebro-geometric setting. Not every complex manifold is projective. Maybe you'll get more clarification by posting the context.

Comment: This is also what i believe, after all, this is a common procedure (e.g studying Lefshetz pencils).